# Creating and checking license numbers

Tags: licensing

To protect software, you can create a validation system which requires users to provide a valid license number (Often 25 letters or digits) which they have to enter with some personal information. This then gets validated (sometimes aby using a validation server, thus requiring online access) and when valid, the user can use the registered version of an application.
Now, simple question: What kinds of solutions are there which would allow developers to implement such a licensing scheme in an easy way into their applications? I could easily create my own solution but I don't want to re-invent the wheel again...

Comment: What programming language / technology are you using for your application?

Comment: Programming language isn't important. Any language will do. Any platform will do too. I'm interested in generic solutions.

Comment: I think this answer explains the basics of a licensing system http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845157/how-to-create-serials-key-to-protect-an-application/12096784#comment16375181_12096784

Comment: [Is there really any way to uniquely identify any computer at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9482253/1699210)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ezirez Intellilock](http://www.eziriz.com/intellilock.htm) has a good solution and API to implement it.

Basicly you created a function of (HW ID, Registration Key) and check if it's right.

Intellilock is just a tool to help you lock the software if the license isn't there.

Comment: But will it also work with WIN32 applications? And on other platforms like Linux, without Mono? And .NET Web applications? And with .NET 4.0? Does it integrate with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: The application works for .NET languages. Doesn't matter what kind of application.