# C# retrieving MAC address, HHD size, ram, OS version information

Tags: c#

I have been working with the Win32 Classes for Windows and putting together an inventory program for Windows based machines (obviously).

Is there a way to gather the system information through a program and dump the information into a text file?

I am looking to retrieve hardware information (MAC addresses, hard drive size.
installed ram, OS version, etc)

Thanks in advance

Comment: WMI classes. Please look at this question which could give you an head start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546228/how-to-detect-the-original-mac-address-after-it-has-been-spoofed/9546552#9546552

Comment: @JMJ, does "Mac" in the title refer to MAC Addresses or Macintosh?

Comment: @TimLehner I fixed the title.

Answer (score 2):

For the Mac address, you can find it using the System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface class.

```
static string GetMacAddress()
{
  string macAddresses = "";
  foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
  {
    // Find all ethernet MACs
    if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet) 
    {
        macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
    }
  }
  return macAddresses;
}
```

To find other system specs programatically, you can use something similar to the code below. If you go to the MSDN page for the [Environment class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8te35sa.aspx), you can find more useful system information.

```
public string SysInfo() 
{
    Stringbuilder systemInformation = new Stringbuilder(string.Empty);

    systemInformation.AppendFormat("Operation System:  {0}\n", Environment.OSVersion);
    systemInformation.AppendFormat("ProcessorCount:  {0}\n", Environment.ProcessorCount);
    systemInformation.AppendFormat("SystemDirectory:  {0}\n", Environment.SystemDirectory);
    systemInformation.AppendFormat("UserDomainName:  {0}\n", Environment.UserDomainName);
    systemInformation.AppendFormat("UserName: {0}\n", Environment.UserName);

    foreach (System.IO.DriveInfo drive in System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        // Get each drive
        systemInformation.AppendFormat("\t Drive: {0}" +
                  "\n\t\t VolumeLabel: {1}" + 
                  "\n\t\t DriveType: {2}" +
                  "\n\t\t DriveFormat: {3}" +
                  "\n\t\t TotalSize: {4}" +
                  "\n\t\t AvailableFreeSpace: {5}\n",
                  DriveInfo1.Name, DriveInfo1.VolumeLabel, DriveInfo1.DriveType, 
                  DriveInfo1.DriveFormat, DriveInfo1.TotalSize, DriveInfo1.AvailableFreeSpace);
    }

    return systemInformation.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you SO much for asking this question.  I am doing an identical project and this was VERY helpful.

The answers were exactly what I needed.

I suggest an edit to winglerw28's code snippet for the SysInfo() function:

```
        systemInformation.AppendFormat("\t Drive: {0}" +
              "\n\t\t VolumeLabel: {1}" + 
              "\n\t\t DriveType: {2}" +
              "\n\t\t DriveFormat: {3}" +
              "\n\t\t TotalSize: {4}" +
              "\n\t\t AvailableFreeSpace: {5}\n",
              DriveInfo1.Name, DriveInfo1.VolumeLabel, DriveInfo1.DriveType, 
              DriveInfo1.DriveFormat, DriveInfo1.TotalSize, DriveInfo1.AvailableFreeSpace);
```

I'm pretty sure the "DriveInfo1" references should all be changed to "drive" as follows:

```
                systemInformation.AppendFormat("\t Drive: {0}" +
                      "\n\t\t VolumeLabel: {1}" +
                      "\n\t\t DriveType: {2}" +
                      "\n\t\t DriveFormat: {3}" +
                      "\n\t\t TotalSize: {4}" +
                      "\n\t\t AvailableFreeSpace: {5}\n",
                      drive.Name, drive.VolumeLabel, drive.DriveType,
                      drive.DriveFormat, drive.TotalSize, drive.AvailableFreeSpace);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SystemInfo for this. its a command line tool which gives information about everything.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491007.aspx

To dump to text file

```
C:\systeminfo >>C:\a.txt
```

This should generate the file with information.

if you want the invoke this command from a C# application you can launch a process using
System.Diagnostic.Process to run the same command and the file will be generated.

Comment: Its sort of like saying run msinfo32 it has information on everything. The OP needs to be able to retrieve the information from c#, can you include code that demonstrates that?

Comment: Sorry about that as i Understand he wanted to dump that information to text file using some program so i thought of this and using re directional operators this can be dumped to a file. I'll make an edit

Comment: MAC in the subject refers to the MAC address.  I just tried running:
C:\systeminfo >>c:\a.txt
from the terminal and it says that the systeminfo command could not be found (?)
I want to retrieve information from the Macintosh environment.  I'm aware of the Win32 classes for windows and have already written an extensive program around several of them.  I am looking for information that is the equivalent of the Win32 classes on the Macintosh

-J