# How to create 30-character license keys?

Tags: java, algorithm, licensing

The commercial software my company creates and sell currently uses a Base-64 encoded RSA-encrypted license key. The result is roughly 90 characters long. It is bulky and awkward to use, and prone to user error. Some users don't understand copy and paste very well and try to manually type the key.

I'd like to replace the current algorithm with an approach that creates a smaller key, such as the 30-characters keys I see some other programs use. Furthermore, I notice that many software vendors use keys that only use digits and upper-case characters, making them even less cumbersome to use.

What algorithm can I use to generate reasonably secure keys that embed username, product id, and version number, where the resulting license key is no longer than 30 characters and uses only digits and upper-case characters?

(If important, we're coding in Java.)

So...here's a start:

```
public String createLicenseKey(String customerName, String productId, String versionNumber) {
    // what goes here?
    return licenseKey;
}

String key = createLicenseKey("Max Headroom", "ABCD", "4");
// key should now be in format AAAAAA-AAAAAA-AAAAAA-AAAAAA-AAAAAA
```

Answer (score 3):

I followed the links mentioned in fcm's answer, and that led me to a possibility. You'll need Google's Guava libraries in your Java classpath:

```
import com.google.common.hash.HashCode;
import com.google.common.hash.HashFunction;
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;

public class ScratchSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userName = "Max Headroom";
        String productKey = "ABCD";
        String versionNumber = "4";

        final String licenseKey = createLicenseKey(userName, productKey, versionNumber);
        System.out.println("licenseKey = " + licenseKey);

    }

    public static String createLicenseKey(String userName, String productKey, String versionNumber) {
        final String s = userName + "|" + productKey + "|" + versionNumber;
        final HashFunction hashFunction = Hashing.sha1();
        final HashCode hashCode = hashFunction.hashString(s);
        final String upper = hashCode.toString().toUpperCase();
        return group(upper);
    }

    private static String group(String s) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (i%6==0 && i > 0) {
                result += '-';
            }
            result += s.charAt(i);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: How to validate generated license key for client application?

Answer (score 1):

For something so specific, you'll probably have to generate your own algorithm, comprising the required information into the hash in a way only your software would "understand".

Take the info (username, id, version), add a secret salt to it, to add an extra layer of security.

You have the right idea with your code so far, but just there's not much set in stone in regards of specific keys.

Take a look at similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845157/how-to-create-serials-key-to-protect-an-application?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599837/how-to-generate-and-validate-a-software-license-key?rq=1) for more information on the subject.